# Возможность добавления блока поддержки разработчиков в google play

Tags: android, google-play

Всем привет, будет ли Гугл плей ругаться, если я добавлю в приложение блок поддержки разработчиков, где можно будет скопировать банковскую карту?

Comment: Я где то читал что вроде не должно ругаться, добровольная поддержка в приложениях разрешена!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть прецеденты бана приложения только за то, что разработчик оставил ссылку на свой сайт а уже на сайте оставил ссылку на "донат" за это приложение.

Так что выводы делайте сами.

На Google начинают давить антимонопольные комитеты в разных странах и какие то изменения или уже есть, например это разрешили в Южной Корее, или ожидаются в ближайшем будущем.